# Android - Spinner + setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android, spinner, onclicklistener

So, i want to assign a Spinner OnClick, but i get the following error

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call   setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
```

I need it to collect data when i click the spinner, then use it later.
I know i did it before, but i lost the code. Googled for an answer, i didn't find anything that works. 
If this helps, I am using pagerview layout.
Here is my code:

```
     public class DATA extends Fragment {
         public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

  ScrollView GPU_LAYOUT = (ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.gpu, container, false);

      final TextView higher_than =(TextView) GPU_LAYOUT.findViewById(R.id.gpu_higher_than_value);

        final Spinner min_max =(Spinner) GPU_LAYOUT.findViewById(R.id.min_max_spinner_gpulay);  

        min_max.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String TMP=min_max.getSelectedItem().toString();
                higher_than.setText(TMP);
            }
        });

       return GPU_LAYOUT;
      }
```

Is there any way i can do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm doing it like this:

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.GPU_LAYOUT);  
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new myOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

public class myOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {       
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,long arg3)     {           

int position=Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.GPU_LAYOUT)).indexOf(fecha);           }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {        }       
}
```

Also I suggest to get the position of the group you're using and then handle it.

Comment: "I need it to collect data when i click the spinner". Please read my post! I don't need OnItemSelectedListener. Also, GPU_LAYOUT is the main ScrollView.

Comment: Maybe you should do something llike this:
public static class CustomSpinner extends Spinner{
private OnSpinnerEventsListener mListener;
@Override
public boolean performClick()
{mOpenInitiated = true;
 if (mListener != null) 
{//here capture the data you want
mListener.onSpinnerOpened();}
return super.performClick();}
public void setSpinnerEventsListener(OnSpinnerEventsListener OnSpinnerEventsListener) {
mListener = onSpinnerEventsListener;
}

public void performClosedEvent() {
mOpenInitiated = false;
if (mListener != null) {
mListener.onSpinnerClosed();
}
}

}

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with setOnTouchListener in that way:

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min_max.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

    //whatever your logic is put it here 
 }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry, you misunderstood. I need to use setOnClickListener to collect some data when i press the spinner, not when i sellect an item from it.

Comment: okay may be this will help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447063/spinner-get-state-or-get-notified-when-opens

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `setOnClickListener` directly on a Spinner. If you want to do it here is a trick.

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.sp_category:
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)//replacing with onclick
            {
                //Perform any action
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In this code `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` will make this touch act like onclick.
Hope it will help you!