# How to know when the action bar menu is expanded?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have a plain action bar menu like this:

[image]

This is what it looks like in Java:

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
        //when an item is selected (i.e local/My Places/etc)
        return false;
    }
};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[] { "Local", "My Places", "Checkins", "Latitude" });

getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
```

The callback for when an item is selected works fine, but I want a callback for when the dropdown is opened/closed.

I've looked at `ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener` but the following prints nothing in my console.

```
ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener listener = new ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMenuVisibilityChanged(boolean isVisible) {
        System.out.println("hello world!");
    };
};

getActionBar().addOnMenuVisibilityListener(listener);
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Its a boolean, have you tried `if(isvisible){ system.out.println("hello world"); }`

Comment: Yep I have, the issue is that there is **no output**. If the if statement was what I was missing, I should have still got an output on expand and compress.

Comment: I would rather use a toolbar from the support library and adding a Spinner within that toolbar

Comment: The only difference i see between the 2 is that you use `new OnNavigationListener() ` and for the other `new ActionBar.OnMenuVisibilityListener()` , maybe thats the problem. Just a guess tho, maybe that don't matter.

Comment: No difference, I imported ActionBar, so I can leave it in or take it out.

Comment: OnMenuVisibilityListener  is called when you will click ActionBar's Options Item Icon (3 dots, in which you see Settings.).

Comment: That's what I thought too. I'm thinking there's on onclick event for the actionbar itself, or at least a way to get the spinner element from the actionbar and then attach the event onto it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I face the same task. And I use the same method to show `Spinner`.

But to solve this I have to replace this `Spinner` with custom one. I remove this code and put own `Spinner` through xml layout of my activity.

```
<com.company.yourapp.View.MenuSpinner
        android:id="@+id/catalogue_menu_spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/catalogue_status_bar"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp" />
```

Class that notify me when menu is showed (`MenuSpinner` in code above) I get from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447063/spinner-get-state-or-get-notified-when-opens) question.

I hope my answer will help someone who like me stuck on this.