# Android Spinner (DropDown): How to know when its clicked (Expanded) and when an item is chosen?

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner which is already made and working, what i need to do is "know" when the user clicks on the spinner to choose an item (when its expanded) and when the user clicks on an item inside the spinner (whatever that item is).

I'm asking this because i need to un-display two EditText box on first click and then after he/she choose an item i will redisplay them.

any help is appreciated!
thank you

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/hatten.ttf");

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater =getLayoutInflater();
        View test=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        TextView label=(TextView)test.findViewById(R.id.company);
        label.setText(beverage[position]);
        label.setTypeface(font);

        return test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**you can verify of the spinner state with:**

```
if(yourSpinner.isShown()){
   editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else{
    editText.setVisibility(View.GONE)
}
```

Comment: hi maycon, where can i put this condition? i am using adapter class if that helps ill edit the first question

Comment: you can use combining the click event and the back button

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "OnSpinnerEventsListener".
There is a more detailed answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18636385/2391145

Comment: thanks alex! thats actually what i need, but i am unable to implement it! where can i add the action that should take place in case opened or in case its closed? thanks