# How to hide navigation bar when spinner open

Tags: android

I was able to set Immersive mode in my app that properly hides `navigation` and `status bars` in almost every case. The only exclusion I found so far is, that when I tap on a `Spinner` component that has
 `android:spinnerMode="dropdown"`,  the `navigation bar` still comes up. It disappears after I select an item from the dropdown, but I want it to not show up at all. Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: use onWindowsFocuschanged to find whether spinner is opened or not and then if spinner is open then write the code to hide navigation bar... for more details follow the- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447063/spinner-get-state-or-get-notified-when-opens)

Comment: How to use Custom Spinner in my code .

Comment: follow this link it will help you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694786/how-to-customize-a-spinner-in-android) or google for custom spinner tutorial

Comment: I have used that code only,but it is not working.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. @Anchal did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this, although this didn't fit my needs well enough, it still prevents a window focus change, which is what causes the system UI to show up. Sorry it's in Kotlin

#### In your activity's `onCreate()`

```
try {
    val popup = Spinner::class.java.getDeclaredField("mPopup")
    popup.isAccessible = true

    // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
    val popupWindow = popup.get(yourSpinnerView) as android.widget.ListPopupWindow

    popupWindow.isModal = false
} catch (e: Throwable) {
    // silently fail...
}
```

The important part is this line:

```
popupWindow.isModal = false
```

This doesn't affect the spinner interactions, at least for me it still registers clicks properly and hides when a tap occurs outside the popup. However, it doesn't capture all taps, so touching other screen elements will trigger their `onClickListener` as well as hide the spinner. Because of that, I've decided to not use this method and just deal with the Nav bar appearing, since I couldn't get what I wanted by using this.

Hope this helps others, as it took me the better part of a week to figure this out. I wish Android didn't consider opening a spinner as a window visibility change, removing all window flags and killing immersive mode.

**EDIT**: Removed the custom class, opting for the simplest solution which is very easy to implement.

Comment: How to do it in Java? @Mick Ashton

Comment: It didn't work. If someone have the same problem, refer to this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60462764/8432542