# How to make spinner drop top instead of the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

Actually im trying to create a container with droptop menu from which user can select element which will be displayed in container. Answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34862125/dropdown-buttons-spinner-like-the-ones-on-the-design-specs-from-google) question almost fit right for me, but then i stuked with making spinner to open top instead of the bottom.

[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZryW.png)

Comment: Based on the space available in the Screen, Spinner will decide to show the popup on top or bottom.
Instead why don't you use an alert dialog or an activity and set it to Dialog style

Comment: Well, im just not sure for now how to implement this better. My spinner will be placed on bottom of the screen as a part of fragment so dialog is not a best option. And also left part of it should work like a button and right part(that little arrow) should show spinner list with elements