# AppCompatSpinner: change layout when dialog is opened and closed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, android-appcompat

I have a nice green background that I'm displaying behind the spinner - the spinner sits in front of the background.

You can see that it looks really bad as the spinner can be clearly distinguished from it's background.

I would like to make the spinner background transparent when the dialog for the spinner is **CLOSED**. When the dialog is **OPENED**, the spinner can then take on the darker green. Currently, when the dialog is **OPENED or CLOSED**, the same darker green is used in the layout:

**CURRENT LOOK OF SPINNER WHEN CLOSED:**

[image]

**WHAT I WANT THE SPINNER TO LOOK LIKE WHEN CLOSED**

[image]

**WHAT THE SPINNER LOOKS LIKE WHEN OPENED:**

[image]

I load the spinner using an adapter by doing this:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> ageAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.spinner_age, R.id.spinner_item, generateAgeRange());
    ageSpinner.setAdapter(ageAdapter);
```

I know that the `R.layout.spinner_age` xml determines how the spinner layout would look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@color/primary_darker"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        tools:text="Hello"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to load a layout xml for when the dialog is CLOSED and when the dialog is OPENED so that I can achieve the effect I want?

Comment: can you post the layout you want for closed and open. Also it might help if the screenshots weren't clipped.

Comment: I have posted an updated screenshot for what I want the spinner to look like when it is opened - can you see what I want to do? I just want a transparent background for the spinner when it is closed and a dark green background when it is opened.

Comment: if that's all you want to change it would be more efficient to call `spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_background);`

Comment: I can use the setBackgroundResource code provided that there is a listener that is called when the spinner dialog is opened and when it is closed. Then I can set a specific background for when it is opened and closed using the setBackgroundResource code. Is there a listener like that?

Comment: Requires a subclass of spinner.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447063/spinner-get-state-or-get-notified-when-opens

Comment: Using a drop down spinner mode might also give you a similar desired effect with less effort.

Comment: Solved using a custom adapter. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED - you can use the following adapter to achieve the desired effect:

```
package com.example.simon.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.simon.activities.R;

import java.util.List;


public class GenderSpinAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context1;
    private String[] data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public GenderSpinAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public GenderSpinAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public GenderSpinAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    public GenderSpinAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        context1 = context;
        data = objects;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context1
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public GenderSpinAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    public GenderSpinAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getNormalView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    // This funtion called for each row ( Called data.size() times )
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_gender, parent, false);

        TextView tvCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item);

        tvCategory.setText(data[position].toString());

        return row;
    }

    // This funtion called for each row ( Called data.size() times )
    public View getNormalView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_transparent, parent, false);

        TextView tvCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item);

        tvCategory.setText(data[position].toString());

        return row;
    }
}
```