# Hide keyboard on ListView Spinner click

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, android-spinner

How can I hide soft keyboard on Spinner click when this Spinner is in ListView? Basically I want to hide keyboard when Spinner list with data is on.

Comment: You can make a custom spinner with open and close events and when spinner is opened then you can close your keyboard programmatically in its open event code.Refer this link for reference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447063/spinner-get-state-or-get-notified-when-opens

Answer (score 1):

#### setOnFocusChangeListener Callback Listener For Spinner

```
Spinners.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

 @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {

   if(view.getID()==R.id.do_excutive_spinner)
   {
       Hide_Key();
   }
}
```

#### Hide Virtual Keyboard Code

```
public void Hide_Key() {
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create this method:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(View v) {
    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getApplicationWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

pass it the view object. Call this method when your spinner is opened or clicked. This should do it, if it does not work, let me know. I'll be happy to help.