# Hide Keyboard when select item from spinner in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I am trying to hide keyboard after selecting an item from `Spinner` but the code is not working and nothing happens. But in other side the same code works in normal fragment.

Here is the method to hide keyboard:

```
public static void hideKeypad(Activity activity) {
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: ###https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447063/spinner-get-state-or-get-notified-when-opens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `rootView` of the `Fragment` because in your method it's see the `getCurrentFocus() == null`, So it will never go to the rest of the code.

This is the right code:

```
public static void hideKeypad(Activity activity, View view) {
if (view != null) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
   }
}
```

Make a class variable `View` and equal it with the `rootView` of the `Fragment` in the `onCreateView()` and use this method anywhere in this `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me in a fragment

```
    public void removePhoneKeypad() {
    if(getActivity().getCurrentFocus()!=null &&getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() != null) {
        System.out.println("getCurrentFocus() in frag");
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) rootView
                .getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        IBinder binder = getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken();
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(binder,
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: ohh. I am also facing issue with closing the keyboard. Most of the  scenarios it is working.