# Remove focus from TextInputLayout when Spinner is selected

Tags: android, android-layout, focus

I have a layout with two TextInputLayouts and a Spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="test.focustest.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="I don't like"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="My favourite"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the code of the activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

When I switch between the two TextInputLayouts the focus works as expected:
This is how it looks, when the first EditText is selected:

[image: First focused]

And this is how it looks, when the second EditText is selected:

[image: Second selected]

However when I select the spinner the last selected TextInputLayout remains focused:
[image]

I would like to remove the focus from both TextInputLayouts when the Spinner opens. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem with help from this post: [Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447063/spinner-get-state-or-get-notified-when-opens)

I added a custom Spinner which would notify my activity to clear the focus when the spinner opens. Here's the code:

```
    public class CustomSpinner extends AppCompatSpinner {

    public interface OnSpinnerEventsListener {
        void onSpinnerOpened(AppCompatSpinner spinner);
        void onSpinnerClosed(AppCompatSpinner spinner);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, int mode) {
        super(context, mode);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int mode) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, mode);
    }

    public CustomSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int mode, Resources.Theme popupTheme) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, mode, popupTheme);
    }


    private OnSpinnerEventsListener mListener;
    private boolean mOpenInitiated = false;

    // implement the Spinner constructors that you need

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        // register that the Spinner was opened so we have a status
        // indicator for when the container holding this Spinner may lose focus
        mOpenInitiated = true;
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onSpinnerOpened(this);
        }
        return super.performClick();
    }

    public void setSpinnerEventsListener(
            OnSpinnerEventsListener onSpinnerEventsListener) {
        mListener = onSpinnerEventsListener;
    }

    public void performClosedEvent() {
        mOpenInitiated = false;
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onSpinnerClosed(this);
        }
    }

    public boolean hasBeenOpened() {
        return mOpenInitiated;
    }

    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasBeenOpened() && hasFocus) {
            performClosedEvent();
        }
    }
}
```

Then the activity implements this interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CustomSpinner.OnSpinnerEventsListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final CustomSpinner spinner = (CustomSpinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    findViewById(R.id.root).clearFocus();
    spinner.setSpinnerEventsListener(this);
}

    @Override
    public void onSpinnerOpened(AppCompatSpinner spinner) {
        View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        findViewById(R.id.root).clearFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSpinnerClosed(AppCompatSpinner spinner) {

    }
}
```

I also added an id to the root LinearLayout: root. So i'm able to clear the focus.