# Custom Spinner ImageView default display in Spinner Title

Tags: android, spinner

I made custom `Spinner` with text and imageview its working fine.and image only visible in spinner selected item not visible for all dropdown item. so issue is that image displaying on spinner title view. please see the red border area on following image that i don't want to display there.
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxfmg.png)

Custom Spinner Adapter

```
public class RoomListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RoomVO> {

int groupid;
Activity context;
List<RoomVO> list;
LayoutInflater inflater;
String mRoomName;

public RoomListArrayAdapter(Activity context, int groupid, int id, List<RoomVO> list,String mRoomName){
    super(context,id,list);
    this.list=list;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.groupid=groupid;
    this.mRoomName = mRoomName;
    roomName = mRoomName;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ){

    View itemView = inflater.inflate(groupid,parent,false);

    RoomVO roomVO = list.get(position);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_spinner_image);
    if(getRoomName().equalsIgnoreCase(roomVO.getRoomName())){
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    TextView textView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_spinner_title);
    textView.setText(list.get(position).getRoomName());


    return itemView;
}
public String roomName = "";

public String getRoomName() {
    return mRoomName;
}

public void setRoomName(String mRoomName) {
    this.mRoomName = mRoomName;
}

public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    return getView(position,convertView,parent);

}

}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli did you check attached image ?

Comment: In image i set the red border in spinner. that spinner title display text with image but i want to display onle text in spinner title

Comment: Text with image display only in spinner dropdown view not spinner title. i hope now you get it.

Comment: You can probably just check if the spinner is closed. When it's closed you set the ImageView as GONE and viceversa. This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18636385/443136

Comment: Thanks for your replay let me try